# Yii2 and table named user_type relation issue with User model of user table

Tags: php, mysql, model, relationship, yii2

I have a `user` table and a `User` model in [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) advanced application. The `User` hasOne relation with `UserType` model which its table is named `user_type` and also it hasOne relation with `Status` model which its table is named `status`. The two models, i.e. `Status` and `UserType`, hasMany relation with `User` model.

The issue in short: In a view that uses `DetailView` widget, I found this problem

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            ['attribute' => 'profileLink', 'format' => 'raw'],
            'id',            
            'email:email',
            'statusName', //This works Fine
            'userTypeName', // This DOES NOT Work
            'roleName',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Using `userTypeName` gives the following error:

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>
> Relation names are case sensitive. common\models\User has a relation
>   named "userType" instead of "UserType".

I tried replace it with `UserTypeName` also gives the same error

**It only works** if I used lazy query i.e `'userType.user_type_name'`!

However, in the `User` model I already defined the attributes for both `statusName` and `userTypeName` in `attributeLabels()` method as the following:

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
        /* Your other attribute labels */
        'roleName' => Yii::t('app', 'Role'),
        'statusName' => Yii::t('app', 'Status'),
        /* ... */
        'userTypeName' => Yii::t('app', 'User Type'),
        'userTypeId' => Yii::t('app', 'User Type'),
        'userIdLink' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        ];
    }
```

Also, I defined relation as follows:

```
public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::className(), ['id' => 'status_id']);
    }

public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserType::className(), ['id' => 'user_type_id']);
    }
```

In addition I defined a getter for both `statusName` and `userTypeName` as follows:

```
public function getStatusName()
    {
        return $this->status ? $this->status->status_name : '- no status -';
    }

public function getUserTypeName()
    {
        return $this->userType ? $this->UserType->user_type_name : '- no user type -';
    }
```

I don't able to discover the root of the pron=blem that makes `statusName` works while `userTypeName` does not work. Is there any mistaken naming conventions for the table or the model or even the methods?! Does the table name starts with a name of another related table causes this? i.e `user` and `user_type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply correct `getUserTypeName`, there is a typo :

```
public function getUserTypeName()
{
    return $this->userType ? $this->userType->user_type_name : '- no user type -';
}
```